# how to recover openbox desktop environment

Tags: desktop-environments

I have been using 16.04.1 LTS for some months now. All was good until last night when I logged out and tried to log in choosing openbox from the list of desktops. It seems that I had not downloaded openbox (although it was on the list of desktop environment) because all I get is a black screen with just the arrow pointer. I rebooted and the same thing happened. I rebooted into recovery mode and same thing happened, a black screen. I logged before into other desktops like cinnamon, lubuntu, xfce with no problem at all. Help. Thanks

Comment: So, do you just need to know how to install the `openbox` environment? From what I understand, other desktops are working correctly so... you just need to install it from there?

Answer (score 1):

First, remove any files related to openbox that might be present on your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge openbox obconf obmenu
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

After that, run an update and install the openbox environment:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openbox obconf obmenu
```

Comment: Amc I will give that a try......just did not have time to check the forum...will let you know...thanks